# Dynamic javascript form

Tags: javascript, forms, dynamic

I have a simple form as follows so a user can type the name of a question:

```
<input type="text" id="question_name" name="question_name" value="">Question Name: <br />
<a href="#" id="addanother" onclick="addNewQuestion()">Add Another</a>
<div id="container"/>

<input id="go" name="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn" />
```

I am wanting to create a Javascript function (`addNewQuestion()`) which allows a user to add another question dynamically by clicking the "Add Another" link. All the text boxes with the questions should be displayed on the screen.

I understand that it is using `getElementById` and most likely a `for` loop but I keep hitting a brick wall. Can anyone show me a simple solution please?

Comment: Are you open to jQuery?

Comment: @dave I can actually do this using an array in jquery just fine, but i'm required to use just javascript.

Comment: [Don't use `onclick`.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35093997/3853934)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. Here's a simple example in plain JavaScript. Note that you will either want to avoid using `id`s so they aren't duplicated in the DOM, or you will want to dynamically name them.

```js
function addNewQuestion() {
  var container = document.getElementById("questions");
  var question = document.querySelector(".question"); 
  container.appendChild(question.cloneNode(true));
  return false;
}
```

```css
.question { display: block }
```

```html
<div id="questions">
  <label class="question">
    Question Name:
    <input type="text" value="" />
  </label>
</div>
<a href="#" id="addanother" onclick="return addNewQuestion()">Add Another</a>
```